# ReactJS Can't get a value from a form after Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do something very simple.  I want to just Type into my search box, then onSubmit() pass my value to another function. When I try and console.log my form value, I only get undefined. If I add onChange() to my text box tags it works, but I don't want that. I want my action to begin onSubmit()

```
  handleSearch(event){
    this.setState({query: event.target.value})
    console.log(event.target.value)
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='ontology_tool'>
      <div className='wraper'>
        <div className='search'>
          <div className='search_tool'>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
              <input type="text" name="query"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='selected'>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

PS: I have already binded my function in my constructor() function.

Comment: There are few issues in your code:

1. type= "submit" should be a button.
2. input type="text" should have a value prop set to this.state.query.

Comment: the lexical binding of `this` is wrong. use `handleSubmit = (event) => {}`

Comment: as @corvid said... you need to bind it correctly... you can also bind it on the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need to keep the value somewhere, you need to define a controlled input to keep the value in the state, for example:

```
setQuery = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    query: event.target.value,
  });
}

handleSearch(event){
  // do whatever you want onsubmit
  event.preventDefault();
}

render(){
  return (
    <div className='ontology_tool'>
    <div className='wraper'>
      <div className='search'>
        <div className='search_tool'>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
            <input type="text" name="query" onChange={this.setQuery}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='selected'>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'd recommend using a controlled input instead of messing around with the refs.

Comment: agreed, I'd also prefer that to refs.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Can you explain why you used arrow notation for SetQuery, but not for handleSearch?

Comment: @Raven an arrow function gets executed on the outer scope, meaning... it will bind to the instance automagically for you, no need to manually bind your functions on the constructor ;)

Comment: @Raven: merely because I am lazy and did not want to change your code. Otherwise, my personal preference is to use arrow functions, purely because they enable me to write less code and I don't have to worry about binding, as Crysfel explained. :)

Comment: If I have several inputs, I only define a single callback and use the `name` for the key on the state: `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Fixed the code

When you type into the input, the state should be updated otherwise you won't receive any value inside the input field.

There are few issues in your code:

1. input type="text" should have a value prop set to this.state.query
2. You need an onchange event binded to input to update the state.

something like:

```
onInputChange(event){
    this.setState({query : event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used that approach of combining onChange & onSubmit. However, it only works if my input type="Submit". When I change it to button it does not work. It appears that onSubmit requires a type="Submit" form element!

Answer (score 0):

Event target is not the text field, so that's why undefined pops out on you.

There are two solutions, either add ref (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the textfield

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
<input type="text" name="query"/>
<input ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} type="submit" value="Submit" />

handleSearch(event){
  this.setState({query: this.textInput.value})
  console.log(event.target.value)
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

or add onchange to the textfield *in addition* to the onsubmit. Onchange will populate the state, onsubmit will then read data from the state.

Comment: Thank you. The onChange & onSubmit approach works. I read that refs should be used sparingly and is a legacy feature? What is the best practice for dealing with forms in ReactJS? Is it the method you suggested (making two functions to deal with change & submit)?

Comment: As you and @Crysfel pointed out, refs should be used sparingly. The reason behind this is it breaks the idea of the unidirectional dataflow. The key idea of React is that everything renders due to a state or props change. And every event gets data only from parameters, state or props. Refs are neither of them. They are, essentially, a parallel flow and can cause the logic to be more complicated than it needs to be.